# SSH stopped working when I switched to a dynamic WAN IP

Tags: ubuntu, router, ssh, port-forwarding, openssh

Mission: Connect to mwk-desktop from mwk-laptop remotely using SSH.

Situation:

- **Used to work**: I used to be able to connect remotely, but lost the ability. Here's a correlation I noticed:

  - My router had a static WAN IP but now has a dynamic WAN IP. The WAN IP likely changed during this change.

    - Note: The remote machine (mwk-laptop) knows the dynamic WAN IP, despite it being dynamic.
- **SSH server is working**: I can connect to mwk-desktop from mwk-laptop using SSH when mwk-laptop is on the LAN and when I use mwk-ws's LAN IP, as opposed to the router's WAN IP. No password is needed because mwk-laptop's public key is in mwk-desktop's authorized_keys file.
- What changed since the last time it worked:

  - **From static to dynamic WAN IP**: The router for the mwk-desktop's LAN has a dynamic WAN IP.
  - Maybe other things.
- What hasn't changed:

  - **SSH server is running**: mwk-desktop is running an SSH server on port XXXX on Ubuntu 16.04.
  - **Remote machine's public key is in SSH server's authorized_keys file**.
  - **Remote machine is truly remote**: mwk-laptop is using my phone's mobile hotspot to connect to the Internet, and is running Ubuntu 16.04. This is how I'm testing remote access. It's not connected to mwk-desktop's LAN.
  - **Static LAN IP**: mwk-desktop has a static LAN IP.
  - **Remote machine knows WAN IP**: mwk-laptop knows the WAN IP of mwk-desktop's router.

    - (Each hour I write the WAN IP to mwk-desktop's Dropbox folder and read it from mwk-laptop's Dropbox folder.)

      - (I might use a dynamic DNS service later.)
  - **Portforwarded**: The router is portforwarding traffic on port XXXX to mwk-desktop.
  - **ISP**: Comcast
  - **Router**: ASUS RT-AC5300
  - **SSH software**:

    - Server: sudo apt-get install **openssh-server**
    - Client: sudo apt-get install **openssh-client**
- What I've done since the change:

  - **I updated my router's firmware**.

Answer (score 0):

**I had to portforward twice.**

I had to portforward my SSH port from my XFINITY box to my ASUS router, in addition to portforwarding from my ASUS router to the machine with the SSH server (mwk-desktop).

---

Why:

When I switched services I not only went from a static WAN IP to a dynamic WAN IP, but I also added an intermediate device that was blocking ports (the XFINITY box):

Internet --> XFINITY box --> router --> machine with SSH server

While before it was:

Internet --> router --> machine with SSH server

And so, I had to portforward twice.

Comment: If you want to avoid this, you can set the Xfinity gateway to bridged mode.